# Insert new line after every line in python

Tags: python, text, file-io, edit, fileinputstream

absolute novice to python here just trying to automate some processes. After doing some research, i have understood that fileinput can be used to open, read, and write to files in python. In order to solve my problem, i believe that i need to:

- open the file
- create a backup of the file
- read the file
- create a for loop for the number of lines in file
- execute the creation of a new line
- go to next line and repeat
- save and close the file

I could not figure out from the documentation from docs.python the method/functions required to carry this out, and after reading some other posts i was frankly even more confused because they suggested to use other modules aswell.

Any and all help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: If you use the `fileinput` module with its `inplace=True` option, you don't need to do most of that stuff. It automatically makes the backup for you. You just read from the file and write to standard output, and it makes the right thing happen.

Comment: This is a trivial problem. Please show how far you could get (post your code).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample program that

1. makes a backup of an existing file,
2. reads the lines of the existing file,
3. saves modified lines to a new file, and
4. tracks the number of lines.

This example is meant to show off some of the core features of Python.  For example, it shows how to use loops, how to open files, and how to work with strings in Python.

Suppose you have a file called *somefile.txt*:

```
This is a file.
Hi to you!
```

And suppose you have a file named *example.py* in the same directory, containing these lines:

```py
import shutil # file copy
import os     # new line separator

# the full path of the file
path = "somefile.txt"

# path to where to back it up
backup_path = "somefile.txt.bak"

# path to save output file
output_path = "output.txt"


# create backup first
shutil.copyfile(path, backup_path)

lineNumber = 0

# open the file for reading
with open(path) as input:

    # open output for writing
    with open(output_path, "w") as output:

        # keep reading lines
        while True:
        
            # read a line from input
            line = input.readline()
        
            # end of file?            
            if line == "":
                # break out of `while` loop
                break            
                
            lineNumber += 1
    
            # do something with the line    
            line = str(lineNumber) + ": " + line
        
            # save to output
            output.writelines(line)
    
# files are automatically closed for you
```

If you open the command line in the directory containing example.py and execute it, you should see two new files:

- somefile.txt.bak - a backup of somefile.txt
- output.txt - a modified version of somefile.txt